# Why does panda flatten out arrays?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that looks like this :

```
         date   temperature
0    2021-6-1  [14.1, 16.5]
1   2021-6-10  [19.0, 18.4]
2   2021-6-11  [24.4, 24.8]
3   2021-6-12  [25.4]
```

That I built with a groupby:

```py
data = data.groupby(['date'])['temperature'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

I would like to sort out every element where the size of the list are not 2, this is what I did:

```py
data = data[data['temperature'].apply(len) == 2]
```

This throws an error, `object of type 'float' has no len()` so I tried to see what was going on, turns out the following :

```
newdataset = newdataset[data['temperature'].apply(lambda x: print(x))]
```

And this just printed out all individual array elements, and not the list.

Why does pandas flatten out such iteration ? How can I:

- Iterate over my lists ?
- keep only 2-lengthed lists ?

##### Edit 1:

This is the info of the table, after building it with groupby / apply :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 92 entries, 0 to 91
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------       --------------  ----- 
 0   date         92 non-null     object
 1   temperature  92 non-null     object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 1.6+ KB
None
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date, temperature]
Index: []
[]
```

As requestes, here some more info :
`df[df['temperature'].str.len().isna()]` gives:

```
Empty DataFrame Columns: [date, temperature] Index: []
```

And `df.to_dict('list')`:

```
{
   'date': ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-10', ...],
   'temperature': [array([14.1, 16.5]), array([19. , 18.4]), ...]
}
```

Comment: Is your `temperature` column contains `nan` values?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM No, and the issue here is mostly the fact that my lambda is applied on individual floats in my lists, and not on the floats themselves.

Comment: Reading again the whole question, are you sure your code is reproducible? I see you're always overwriting the `data` variable (`data = data.do_something()`), which will result in errors if you runs your commands in an incorrect order. Can you start from scratch and make sure of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### remark

I see you repeatedly overwrite your `data` variable, this can cause errors if you run twice the same command or re-run them in a different order.

There is no reason why you should get any of the errors that you describe, unless you re-run the same command.

I would recommend to avoid reusing variables, and even to avoid variables at all.

You can use chained commands to avoid variables:

```
out = (data.groupby(['date'], as_index=False)['temperature'].agg(list)
           .loc[lambda d: d['temperature'].str.len() == 2]
       )
```

##### original answer

You probably have non-iterables in your column (maybe NaNs?).

Use [`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) which will ignore invalid items:

```
data = data[data['temperature'].str.len() == 2]
```

Alternatively, using a list comprehension:

```
data = df[[isinstance(l, list) and len(l)==2 for l in df['temperature']]]
```

Output:

```
        date   temperature
0   2021-6-1  [14.1, 16.5]
1  2021-6-10  [19.0, 18.4]
2  2021-6-11  [24.4, 24.8]
```

Example of input that would trigger an error with the original approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-10', '2021-6-11', '2021-6-12',  '2021-6-13'],
                   'temperature': [[14.1, 16.5], [19.0, 18.4], [24.4, 24.8], [25.4], float('nan')]})
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure all my elements are at least lists, since I built them with a list constructor. Worst case scenario would be an empty list, or list with NaN. Furthermore, printing out all values should show me arrays, not all the floats ?

Thank you for the solution, but it does not work (it throws an empty dataframe, because it acts on floats and not lists)

Comment: What is the output of `df[df['temperature'].str.len().isna()]`? Can you also provide a reproducible constructor for your input (output of `df.to_dict('list')`) to make sure of the types?

Comment: I've added the df.info() in the question, the types are `objects`

Comment: @LucioleMaléfique `object` could mean many things (including strings), can you provide what I requested?

Comment: `data = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-6-1', '2021-6-10'], 'temperature': [np.array([14.1, 16.5]), np.array([19. , 18.4])]})` certainly does **not** return an empty dataframe after running `data[data['temperature'].str.len() == 2]`, so I'm not sure what you're doing, but it's not reproducible. Given the initially reported error (`TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()`), you **must** have floats in your "temperature" column.